# $\dim (A/I) \le \dim (A)$

Tags: abstract-algebra, ideals, krull-dimension

> Let $A$ be a ring and $I$ be an ideal. I'm trying to prove that $\dim (A/I) \le \dim (A)$.

**My attempt to proof**

Suppose that $\dim (A)=n$, then there are prime ideals $\mathfrak p_0,\ldots,\mathfrak p_n$ such that $\mathfrak p_0\subsetneq\ldots\subsetneq\mathfrak p_n$.

Then if I prove chain bellow

$$\mathfrak p_0/I\subsetneq\ldots\subsetneq \mathfrak p_n/I$$

is a chain of prime ideals, we're done. The problem is I don't know why $I\subset \mathfrak p_i, 0\le i\le n$.

It should be a silly thing, I need help.

Thanks

Comment: could you not use lagrange?  I must be a subgroup of I, meaning it has on order less than or equal to that of A, so you can show it must be less than the order of A (by assuming I={1}), and greater than or equal to one (if I=A).

Comment: @MalcolmLazarow I don't know how Lagrange could be useful in this question since we don't know almost anything about the order of the subgroups. Thanks for your comments!

Comment: Dear @user42912, In case it's not apparent from the answer of Nilay Kumar, you cannot prove that $I\subset\mathfrak{p}_i$ because there's no reason this has to be true if $I\neq 0$.

Comment: @KeenanKidwell yes, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recall that the primes of $A/I$ are in inclusion-preserving one-to-one correspondence with the primes of $A$ containing $I$. For a proof of this (and related facts), see for example Zariski-Samuel's Commutative Algebra I, sections III.4-III.8.

The argument proceeds by a simple contradiction. If $\dim A/I >\dim A=n$, then there must exist a chain of primes in $A/I$ with length more than $n$. By the fact above, there exists a corresponding chain of primes in $A$ (containing $I$) of length more than $n$. This contradicts that $\dim A=n$.

The fact above, in addition to the fact that the primes of $A_{\mathfrak{p}}$ are in inclusion-preserving one-to-one correspondence with the primes of $A$ contained in $\mathfrak p$, are very good to keep in mind, especially in the context of dimension theory.